# Как упаковать каталоги в отдельные архивы?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Есть около 40 каталогов, и каждый необходимо запаковать в архив со своим именем. Стандартными средствами получается создать только один архив, содержащий все каталоги.

Упаковать нужно с помощью программы *zip*.

Пытался написать простой *bash*-скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
for folder in * # Не знаю как обознать все папки
do
zip -m $file.zip $folder
done
echo
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Зипуем все поддиректории 

for folder in *
do
    if [ -d $folder ] 
    then
    # Это директория - зипуем её
    echo "Зипуем поддиректорию $folder"
        zip -r ${folder}.zip $folder > /dev/null
    fi
done
echo Работа завершена
```

Answer (score 10):

Обойти все папки в текущем каталоге позволяет конструкция

```
for d in */; do; ...; done
```

Тем самым скрипт примет следующий вид:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */
do
    echo "Zipping folder \"$d\"..."
    zip -m $d.zip $d
done
```

Имейте в виду, что скрипт "не видит" скрытые каталоги (имена которых начинаются с точки) и работает не вполне корректно, если в текущем каталоге нет подкаталогов.

---

Всех этих недостатков лишён следующий скрипт, использующий в своей работе команду `find`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in $( find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path . )
do
    echo "Zipping folder \"$d\"..."
    zip -m $d.zip $d
done
```

Первый скрипт обрабатывает также символические ссылки, второй их пропускает. Если их также необходимо обрабатывать, нужно добавить команде `find` ключ `-L`:

```
find -L . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path .
```